# A weird thing About ActiveRecord .find(id) method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

If I have a Post model of ID 1,

I can access this resource by

```
 http://localhost:3000/posts/1
```

but weired thing is that when I use these URL, I can get the same result.

```
 http://localhost:3000/posts/1somethingweird-blah-blah-blah-idont-like-this
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: This is because .find essentially just takes whatever param you pass in and does a to_i on it, so the string `'1somethingweird-blah-blah-blah-idont-like-this'.to_i` would return 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely because `params[:id]` is being converted from a `String` to an `int` and in Ruby calling `"1somethingweird-blah-blah-blah-idont-like-this".to_i` will actually result in `1`.

You can fix this at the route level:

```
resources :posts, :constraints => {:id => /[0-9]+/}
```

Comment: Basically the .find(x) expects the x to be an integer for id and converts it so..

Comment: @bullfrog Yes, exactly. Most languages would fail on a conversion of that `String` to `int`, but Ruby likes to be pragmatic. :)

Comment: On a side note this is a quick way to have pretty urls for your rails app instead of boring old ids :)

Answer (score 1):

Two main options:

1. [Put a constraint on the route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints).
2. Validate the parameter in the controller (e.g., with a regex).

The reason it works is because `"1abc".to_i == 1`.